# PHP Date Object Add 3 Seconds

Tags: php, date, time, propel

I want to add 2 seconds for current date object, I am getting data objects as propel foreach array result, this is the object I receive

```
DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2020-05-22 09:03:21.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => Australia/Melbourne
    )
```

I tried this ways but no any change,

```
$row->getStartTime()->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('+2 seconds'));

$row->getStartTime()->add(new DateInterval('PT2S'));
```

But I am unable to get the new with 2 seconds added for received time.

Comment: Please add the actual code you use (which is relevant to this problem).  Do you store the value of `$row->getStartTime()->add` - does your foreach use references for `$row`?

Comment: $row->getStartTime(); this the time object I receive.

Comment: I tried above mentioned 2 options but failed add add 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = $row->getStartTime()->format('H:i:s'); 
$callTimeMax = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+3 seconds', strtotime($time)));
```

This is my approach, It worked.